# Change Background color on click

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making a simple program in Android that whenever I click on the blank screen, the screen changes its color. Can anyone help me. How can I use the onclick function on blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your background like so:

```
layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutname);
layout.setBackgroundColor(AndroidColor);// can be a drawbale file or a string for colours
```

Then there is a few ways you could do the click to change the background. I would add a ontouch listener to the layout. When true (user presses the screen) the code I gave above is called. You will need to edit what I give as I don't know your naming scheme but something like this should do the job:

```
layout .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        layout.setBackgroundColor(AndroidColor);
        return true;
    }
});
```